# Path analysis for longitudinal data

Tags: repeated-measures, panel-data, structural-equation-modeling

I want to conduct a path analysis for longitudinal data with t = 13 (the model is presented below). Is it possible to make a path model for each individual at each time point? I am quite familiar with some R packages.

[image: path model]